# Push example android gcm, registered device but do not receive push notification

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications (gcm) using example from Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. extras/google/samples/
I set up server and i can register device on it, it returns registration id but doesn't push notification to mobile device.

things i have changes from sample: server - api key (browser/server tried both)
on client side: SERVER_URL and SENDER_ID

on html page that is included with demo example after run application : 1 device(s) registered!(with logs i can see that id and looks correct), after push Send Message : Sent message to one device: [ messageId=0:1369738939369676%921c249af9fd7ecd ]and it doesnt show up on mobile device.

What could be a problem, about what did i forgot?

i was able to read response from gcm (i guess) :

```
MulticastResult(multicast_id=6144555349590101172,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1369749519814767%921c249a00000031 ]]
```

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was caused bcs of firewall and blocked ports 5228-5230, admin unblocked that ports and all works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have proper auth token, in your server implementation.

```
String authToken = "AIzacq9Twg20j6g-sas............";
sender = new Sender(authToken);
```

This AuthToken should be taken from GCM portal and it should be mapped to SENDERID, you should use Sender ID in android app.

Comment: checked and that sender id (browser key form google api console) at serwer side is correct for sure
at client side i have sender id as "google project number" as was told in tutorial